# Error con Plugin de nginx para Docker Compose

Tags: nodejs, linux, nginx, docker, docker-compose

tengo un inconveniente al levantar el servicio `kobo-docker_nginx_1` en una maquina virtual con Ubuntu 16.04. Aparece el siguiente error al intentar ejecutar el comando `docker-compose up`:

```
 for kobo-docker_nginx_1 
 Cannot start service nginx: 
 driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint kobo- 
 docker_nginx_1 
 (349f2f01b33f4b0c4974658b42faf9738ac52208fc65a3d33bb1a5edd809244b): 
 Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8005: bind: address 
 already in use
```

Estoy ejecutando por ssh la maquina virtual en Hiper-V en un servidor compartido Windows Server 2012 R2...
muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El contenedor de "kobo-docker_nginx_1" no pudo levantarse correctamente ya que algún otro proceso se encuentra usando el puerto "0.0.0.0:8005".

Para solucionarlo tendrías que matar ese proceso con esto el puerto se libera y luego de nuevo ejecutas el comando "docker-compose up -d".

Antes de matar el proceso tienes que verificar cual es para evitar más inconvenientes.

Te dejo un tutorial muy bueno en vez del puerto "3000" tendrías que aplicarlo con el puerto "8005"

[Linux: Identificando qué proceso está usando un puerto](http://community.logicalbricks.com/node/103)

Comment: el proceso que se ejecuta en ese puerto es necesario para enlazar el contenedor nginx, tiene que esta corriendo en ese puerto, lo extraño es que cuando cambio ese proceso a otro puerto distinto por ejemplo el 8006, cuando observo los logs de nginx aparece esto: standard_init_linux.go: 178: exec user process caused "exec format error" vale aclarar que aunque se produzca el primer mensaje los demas procesos que estan corriendo tambien liberan el segundo mensaje